# Cin overflowing into following cin

Tags: c++, command-line-interface, cin

I have a simple program that works nominally when the input is precisely as expected.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int a, b;
    char ab;

    cin >> a;
    cin >> ab;
    cin >> b;

    cout << a;
    cout << ab;
    cout << b;
}
```

This works perfectly when the inputs are normal; however, when the second `cin` runs, it will input the remainder into the next cin call.

So output of this case would look like:

```
4
454

4
4
54
```

How do I deal with the extra in the `cin` buffer to keep it from going into the next one?

Comment: Read in all inputs as strings, parse them to make sure they are what you expect, if not, repeat, convert to the data type you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `cin` you can use [getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
string input;
getline(cin, input);
```

In this way, you will take input as line so you won't bother with buffer or anythink else. After that, you can parse it.

Comment: Using `stoi` to cast the string to a data type (like int) works fine, but how would you do it for a char? I tried doing `ab = input[0];`

Comment: It's not so much "instead of `cin`" as it is instead of `operator>>`. Both `>>` and `getline` operate on an input stream, and `cin` is the stream that's attached to the console. +1.

Comment: @satazero -- `stoi` does not **cast** the string to a data type; it **converts** the string to the data type.

Comment: @PeteBecker thank you, that is an issue with my terminology that I'm still working on. I have gotten the program working now! Thank you all for your help.